# How to do url routing in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to make a website with joomla 2.5.

Now I want to do something that the urls do not change at all.

I mean that I want that the browser address bar just show the name of the site in all of the pages.

Is there any extensions for it?

EDIT

Now my urls look like the following:

mysite.com/component/k2/66-n-t-shirt-49-detail?Itemid=0

and I want it to be like this:

mysite.com/t-shirt1

Is it possible to change it from htaccess file?

I have changed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess too but it didn't work and it just removed `index.php` from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your site in an iframe or frameset, that will only show the frameset url.

Else you could change all the urls to post, but this will require quite an effort in jQuery and would be quite hard.